# How to add Windows worker nodes to a Rancher HA Cluster provisioned by RKE cluster.yml

Tags: windows, high-availability, worker, rancher

I have provisioned a rancher 3 node HA cluster with rke cluster.yml. Is it possible to add windows worker nodes to the existing cluster?. I was able to add linux worker nodes to the cluster by adding entries into the "cluster.yml" and updating the configuration using "rke up --update-only". Is there any possible way to add windows worker nodes to the existing cluster using rke?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be done with [custom nodes](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/cluster-provisioning/rke-clusters/custom-nodes/)